# if request.method == 'POST' and 'sub' in request.form: is not working in flask: if condition is not executing

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a CRUD operation using flask and sqlalchemy. there're two input fields.

1. Subject and 2) Description and an ADD button. User enters the values and Add it to the database (sqlite3). Fortunately that's working. Even deletion is working.

**But updating a row is not working.**

I'm attaching my **Flask** code.

```
@app.route('/update/<id>/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def update(id):
    subj = ''
    descr = ''
    print("outside the if condition")
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'subb' and 'dess' in request.form:
        print("inside the if condition")
        subj = request.form.get('sub')
        print(subj)
        descr = request.form.get('desc')
        entry = Crud(subject = subj, description = descr)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
    searchThisId = Crud.query.get(id)
    return render_template("update.html",searchThisId = searchThisId)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Update the details {% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
<div>
    <form method = 'POST', action = '/'>
        
        <input type = "text" name = "subb" value = {{ searchThisId.subject }}><br>
        
        <input type = "text" name = "dess" value = {{ searchThisId.description }}><br>

        <input type = "submit" value = "UPDATE">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think you're problem is here: if request.method == 'POST' and 'subb' and 'dess' in request.form:

You're trying to test for "if request.method is post, and both "dess" and "subb" are keys in a dictionaly called request.form" right? That is not what that statement would do as written.

Comment: dess & subb comes from HTML form


   ```   <input type = "text" name = "subb" value = {{ searchThisId.subject }}><br>
        
        <input type = "text" name = "dess" value = {{ searchThisId.description }}><br>```
check the 'name' inside input tags
@MattBlaha

Comment: Right, but flask presents them in request.form as a dictionary? You can call request.form.keys() on it? I'm pretty sure my answer below will work.

Comment: @MattBlaha

Tried your code. But still it's not getting inside the 'if condition'.

Comment: Is that exactly the code you're running? I notice one thing that might be  causing you other problems: sometimes you refer to "desciption" as "desc" and others as "dess" is it consistent in the code you're running?

Comment: @MattBlaha yes. I'm having similar code to add data to database. and that's working though. But here it's not working.

Comment: At least one other problem you seem to have beside the conditional: subj = request.form.get('sub') but in the form the field is named "subb" not "sub".

Comment: yes exactly :) @MattBlaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code like this, and working fine.

```
@app.route('/update/<id>/', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def update(id):
    searchThisId = Crud.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searchThisId.subject = request.form['subb']
        searchThisId.description = request.form['dess']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('Index'))
    else:
        return render_template("update.html",searchThisId = searchThisId)
```

**HTML**

```
    <form method = 'POST', action = "/update/{{ searchThisId.id }}/">
        
        <input type = "text" name = "subb" value = {{ searchThisId.subject }}><br>
        
        <input type = "text" name = "dess" value = {{ searchThisId.description }}><br>

        <input type = "submit" value = "UPDATE">
    </form>
```

Thankyou @MattBlaha for the help.

Comment: Oh nice. Sorry I dropped this thread but looks like your issue was indeed the mismatched field names, and you can do without the conditional. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Flask setup, but I think your problem is here:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'subb' and 'dess' in request.form:
```

This statement is saying "if request.method is POST, and 'subb' is true, and 'dess' is an element of request.form (which is a dictionary I believe -- so this last part is what is always returning false.)

request.form is a dictionary, and you want to check that both 'subb' and 'dess' are keys in that dictionary right?

This should work:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and all(elem in request.form.keys() for elem in ['subb','dess'):
```